# JSON date converting into time string

Tags: javascript, datetime

Running into a JavaScript date weirdness that I cannot wrap my head around.

I have a date/time returned via WebAPI: '2012-12-13T12:17:06.080'.  It's in local time (-7 UTC).

When running this date through JavaScript

```
var d = new Date('2012-12-14T05:32:05.543');
alert(d.toTimeString());
```

returns **22:32:05 MST**

Then doing

```
var d = new Date('2012-12-14T05:32:05.543');
alert(d.toLocaleTimeString());
```

returns **10:32:05 PM**

toTimeString/toLocaleTimeString() per JavaScript docs says it should just extract the Time portion, so why did the time change?  What should I do to get it to return the correct time portion **05:32:05** without creating an supposedly unneeded function?

Comment: Is'nt it obvious? How should new Date know that you already subtracted the seven hours to get local time. It does'nt, so it treats all timestrings the same, and converts them to local time, subracting another seven hours, giving you the wrong time.

Comment: Yes, it's VERY obvious, but @Pointy made the point (ahem) that there's assumptions involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you give the `Date()` constructor an ISO8601 timestamp string, it *always* interprets it as UTC.

Not all browsers behave the same way, and some don't like those at all.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to solve your problem:

> Take the parts of the date and construct the date object manually.

I have attached a JSBin showcasing that http://jsbin.com/iduzaz/3/watch